# Pinit Share not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, share

i jus added a pinit share button to pin my images in posts . Here is the [URL](http://www.glamilyfashion.com/)    .

```
<!--Pin It-->
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"     class="pinit" title="Share this post on Pinterset!" target="_blank"></a>
```

And when i click on it it leads me to  pinit site . and when i click pinit it shows the following error

**You need to upload an image or provide the 'image_url' parameter**

i dont know what wrong i have done. Please help!! thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pinterest needs you pass a media para,
looks like 
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=YOUR_PAGE_URL&media=YOUR_IMGAGE_URL"

you can get post thumbnail image by:

```
    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>
```

Comment: how can i get that image url dnamically in wordpress?

Comment: not worked .. also in my case the homepage post shows 4 images .. here is the link http://www.glamilyfashion.com/

Comment: @Melvin you have to set at least one image as fearture image in a post.

Comment: why cant it take the first image from post instead of featured image?

Comment: @Melvin because when you put images in the content area, WP donesn't really know what that about. it just simple HTML code.